# text input does not appear once user appends a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/11/

The problem I have is that when you open the fiddle, if you click on a couple of buttons from buttons "A-H" and then click on "Add Question" button to append the buttons into a new table row, no text inputs appear underneath the table.

But within the table row if you turn on a different button, then it displays the text input for that button.

What my question is that how can I have the text inputs to appear from the turned on buttons in the top control once the user clicks on the "Add Question" button?

Below is what should happen:

1. Right at the top control, turn on buttons A and D.
2. Click on the "Add Question" button and this should append a row, but it should also display the text inputs for buttons "A" and "D".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored some of the code from `btnclick` to a new method `updateAnswer` which collects all the buttons that are turned on and adds an input to the answer container. The method is then called from `btnclick` and `insertQuestion`.

I updated the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/20/).